# Quasar form validation not triggering

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I have a form in Quasar with some required fields. When I click submit, the form does not trigger validation and doesn't even log anything to the console. I've been staring at it for hours and checking the docs and countless tutorials but can't figure out what could be wrong. When I get rid of the validators, the form submits fine. I removed all the irrelevant logic like queries and such.

```
<template>
  <q-card>
    <q-card-section>
      <div class="text-h6">Add New</div>
    </q-card-section>
    <q-separator />

    <q-card-section style="max-height: 50vh" class="scroll">
      <q-form
        ref="form"
        @submit="onSubmit"
        @cancel="onCancel"
        class="q-gutter-md"
        greedy
      >
        <q-input
          name="name"
          lazy-rules
          :rules="[(val) => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Please type something']"
          v-model="input.name"
          label="Name"
        />
        <q-input
          name="dob"
          v-model="input.dob"
          filled
          type="date"
          hint="Date of birth"
        />
        <q-separator />

        <div>
          <q-btn flat label="Cancel" color="secondary" v-close-popup />
          <q-btn type="submit" flat label="Add" color="primary" v-close-popup />
        </div>
      </q-form>
    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      input: {
        name: null,
        dob: null,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
      const success = await this.$refs.form.validate();
      if (success) {
        console.log("success");
      } else {
        console.log("fail");
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Additionally, I am getting the following error in the console: runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 [Vue warn]: Property "error" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
Any clues on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

My form did not validate because I had it within a dialog. I placed an `@click` on my submit button and removed the `v-close-popup` closing the popup only on submit.